# How to add icon to Action Sheet Popup on Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm using `Action Sheet Popup` of the library [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) on `Xamarin Forms`.

I want to display the image as below:

[image: Add_Icon_On_ActionSheet]

How to add an icon to `Action Sheet Popup` on `Xamarin forms`?

This is my code:

```
    public Task<string> ShowActionSheetDialogAsync(string title, string cancelString = null, string destructive = null, CancellationToken? token = null, string[] arrayButtons = null)
    {
        return UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheetAsync(title, cancelString,destructive, cancelToken: token,buttons:arrayButtons);
    }
```

Or you can suggest another idea which might also show.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [aritchie/userdialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) instead, it provides icon option for the item in list , check [API](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/e627dbfa3a7a3e4f6d002b11744bce6b5a458e11/src/Acr.UserDialogs/ActionSheetOption.cs#L12) .

#### Usage

```
        IUserDialogs d = UserDialogs.Instance;
        ActionSheetConfig config = new ActionSheetConfig();

        List<ActionSheetOption> Options = new List<ActionSheetOption>();
        Options.Add(new ActionSheetOption("1" , null , "info.png"));
        Options.Add(new ActionSheetOption("2", null, "info.png"));

        ActionSheetOption cancel = new ActionSheetOption("Cancel",null,null);

        config.Options = Options;
        config.Cancel = cancel;

        d.ActionSheet(config);
```

### Screen shot

[image]

Comment: Can we add text close to the icon as my image?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't unless you can change the source code ..

Comment: specify the image name in your project folder.

Comment: I misunderstood, I mean if we do not use [aritchie/userdialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs), Can we use another way? Can I add an icon near the text? (as my picture on description question).

Comment: Make your own implementation on each platform , i think it's not difficult .

Comment: Can I use ActionSheetConfig with ActionSheetAsync()?

Answer (score 1):

This is platform-specific, so wrap it in DependencyService for example.

This is how you add image to an ActionSheet action:

```
UIImage img; //the image
var action = new UIAlertAction();
action.SetValueForKey("image", img);
```

Then add this `UIAlertAction` to a `UIActionSheet`. (You should also set Title and Action, of course)

Comment: @iiSpain17 Can you give more specific instructions? I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: Ill get to a PC in the evening, only then can i write full code, sorry. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the above way of @Cole Xia - MSFT ... It work!